# Mysqldump backupt o remote server using ftp command

Tags: mysql, linux, ftp, centos

How i can transfer my backup to a remote server using ftp protocol and ftp command in a single command line?

My mysql dump command

```
mysqldump -u _admin -p'pass&word' _maindb --add-drop-table --ignore-table=_maindb.emailstatstics > backup$(date '+%d_%m_%y_%H_%M').sql
```

And ftp like:

```
ftp 64.xx.xx.xx 
myUserName
myPassword
put myMysqlBackup.sql
```

I need this command to executed in cronjobs in directadmin

Answer (score 1):

This will get the file uploaded. You can put the two lines into a shell script and make it executable and you should have no problem using it from a crontab. Just make sure you use the absolute path to the output file.

```
ftp -u ftp://myUserName:myPassword@64.xx.xx.xx myMysqlBackup.sql
```

Comment: I need to transfer it after the backup has complete. how to write in a shell? im beginer to linux command

Comment: Just put the two lines in a file somewhere with a `.sh` extension and add `#!/bin/sh` as a separate line at the top. This tells the loader to use the `sh` shell to run your script. Then you just need to mark as executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: Sorry, noticed you mentioned DirectAdmin. If you put this script in your user's home directory (outside of the web root - this is important) then you should be able to specify the full path to the script as the "command" in DirectAdmin.

Comment: Your ftp command doesn't work as i needed, but your suggestion to create a shell was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably:

```
FILENAME=backup$(date '+%d%m_%y_%H_%M').sql ; mysqldump -u _admin -p'pass&word' _maindb --add-drop-table --ignore-table=maindb.emailstatstics > $FILENAME ; scp $FILENAME USERNAME:PASSWORD@64.xx.xx.xx/.
```

Comment: It does not work for me, `ftp 64.xx.xx.xx myUserName myPassword put $FILENAME` does not do any thing, i give this message `usage: ftp host-name [port]`

Comment: Ah .. I assumed the ftp command you wrote in your question was a working one. I'll amend the response then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#/bin/bash
archive=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M).gz
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip -9 >  $archive
HOST=backupserver
USER=user
PASS=password
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
put $archive
bye
EOF
rm -f archive
```